# The approximate values of density for a flame with respect to heights

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, density, continuum-mechanics, fluid-statics

I'm aware that the difference in density with respect to height is low, but I'm in need of the values for a project: in which I explain that the continuity equation of fluid dynamics will work well for gases as an approximation since the density difference is not high for different heights of a flame.

p.s: the project is a video explaining the tapering of flame. I also would like to know if showing the values of temperature incase I can't get the values for density would be acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The approximate values of density for a flame with respect to heights
>
> I'm aware that the difference in density with respect to height is low, but I'm in need of the values for a project: in which I explain that the continuity equation of fluid dynamics will work well for gases as an approximation since the density difference is not high for different heights of a flame.

Check out: "[Jet flame heights, lift-off distances, and mean flame surface density for extensive ranges of fuels and flow rates](http://eprints.whiterose.ac.uk/89790/)", (DOI link: https://doi.org/10.1016/J.COMBUSTFLAME.2015.09.009) by Derek Bradley, Philip H. Gaskell, Xiaojun Gu, and Adriana Palacios for formulas to make these calculations:

"The correlations are based on a vast experimental data base, covering 880  flame heights. They encompass pool fires and flares, as well as choked and unchoked jet flames of  CH$_4$, C$_2$H$_2$, C$_2$H$_4$, C$_3$H$_8$, C$_4$H$_{10}$ and H$_2$, over a  wide range of conditions. Supply pressures range from 0.06 to 90 MPa,  discharge diameters from 4·10$^{-4}$ to 1.32 m, and flame heights from 0.08  to 110 m.".

See also: "[The size of flames from natural fires](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0082078463800910)", (11 October 2007) by P.H.Thomas. Origonal paper: [Source: Fire Safety Science Digital Archive](http://iafss.org/publications/frn/497/-1). "This paper discusses one of the least studied features of natural fires - the length of the turbulent flames rising from the burning fuel.".

An answer about backpressure: [Why does exit pressure matches back pressure in a converging diverging nozzle?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/387017/why-does-exit-pressure-matches-back-pressure-in-a-converging-diverging-nozzle/387031#387031)

> PS: The project is a video explaining the tapering of flame.

Here's a great video from NASA: "[NASA’s new High Dynamic Range Camera Records Rocket Test](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nPfcwT4Fcy8)", not much tapering in that view but it's shot in HDR and shows the turbulence of the burning.